# False notifications being sent for tasks

Tags: upgrade

I have notifications being sent for tasks that are complete. The tasks were part of an approval workflow. The tasks and workflow have been complete for 3 to 6 months. The issue started after an upgrade from MOSS 2007 to SPS2010.  I've tried clearing the config cache as some post suggest, but that did not correct the issue.  I’ve been through the ULS and events around the times and not found anything out of the ordinary.  I've also confirmed the tasks complete and mail is off in other environemnts.  Has anyone else run into this?